# RSpec `match` failes when single quote is present

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

RSpec example fails when occasional single quote is present in matcher argument (generated by Faker).

Spec example itself:

```
it 'contains organizer name' do
  expect(mail.body.encoded).to match organizer.name
end
```

Example of an output:

```
1) PriorityRequestMailer#prioritize body contains organizer name
 Failure/Error: expect(mail.body.encoded).to match organizer.name
   expected "<html>...<a href=\"http://zieme-streich_905/events\">Gage O'Reilly</a>...</html>\r\n" to match "Gage O'Reilly"
   Diff:
   @@ -1,2 +1,66 @@
   -Gage O'Reilly
   +<html>
   ....
```

It looks that given name `Gage O'Reilly` is present in body but it fails anyway. What is the cause of such an issue?

Answer (score 4):

You don't typically want to match on `encoded`. In fact the docs for that method say

> Calling this directly is not a good idea, but supported for compatibility

The encoded could be in a different encoding, converted to quoted-printable etc. A better idea is to match against `decoded`. Even better, you can do

```
expect(mail.body).to match(...)
```

since the body object already has a `match` method that does the right thing.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe like so?

```
expect(mail.body.encoded).to include organiser.name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
expect(mail.body).to match(/"#{organiser.name}"/)
```

Or

```
expect(mail.body).to match(organiser.name)
```

It will pass if `expect("a string").to match(/str/)`

so in your case as `"Gage O'Reilly"` should match with the `<html>....Gage O'Reilly...</html>`" string

For your case use the `match`

```
> "<html>...<a href=\"http://zieme-streich_905/events\">Gage O'Reilly</a>...</html>\r\n".match(/Gage O'Reilly/)
=> #<MatchData "Gage O'Reilly">
```

More [here](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers/equality-matchers)

Comment: `match` already converts its argument to a Regex if it isn't already one